# VBA to loop through a range in MS Word

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro that combines multiple Word documents into one. I have managed to do this but what I am now looking for is for this to loop through a specific range. For example, I have a list of 30 word documents in a folder. I need the word macro to go into each of these documents, combining the specific word documents allocated to the master document (which are saved in different folders) and then saving and closing the doc. This needs to be done for all the files in the folder.

So far as mentioned I have only been able to do this for one document at a time by using a userform listbox. This does work but only works for one document at a time. Is there a way to do this for multiple selections from a userform listbox as ideally, I would still like to be able to select which documents I can combine.

This is what I have been using:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim Item1 As String
Dim Number As String
Dim DocNo As String
Dim Today As String


Number = ListBox1.Value
DocNo = DocNotext.Text
Item1 = Left(Number, 4)
Today = Format(Date, "dd mmmm yyyy")


MsgBox ("You will now produce a letter for Dcoument Number. " & Item1 & ".")

Unload Userform1

'open draft template
Set letter = Documents.Open("File path of where main document is stored" & Number, ReadOnly:=False)
On Error Resume Next
letter.Bookmarks("date").Range.Text = Today


If letter.Bookmarks.Exists("APP1") = False Then GoTo LateDoc1:



'insert appendix1
'Go to app1 bookmark:
'On Error GoTo LateDoc1 'skip ahead if can't find app1
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="App1"
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
        "File path for "
'find file in directory
Temp_File_Name = "File Path for first document to be attached to main document" & Item1 & "*"
While File_Name <> ""
File = File_Name
File_Name = Dir
Wend


    Selection.InsertFile FileName:="File Path for first document to be attached to main document" & File _
        , Range:="", ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False 'inserts appendix 1
GoTo App2:



LateDoc1:
App2: 'Insert appendix2
'Go to app2 bookmark:
'On Error GoTo LateDoc2 'skip ahead if can't find app2
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="App2"
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
        "File Path for second document to be attached to main document"
'find file in directory
Temp_File_Name = "File Path for second document to be attached to main document" & Item1 & "*"
File_Name = Dir(Temp_File_Name, vbNormal)
While File_Name <> ""
File = File_Name
File_Name = Dir
Wend


    Selection.InsertFile FileName:="File Path for second document to be attached to main document" & File _
        , Range:="", ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False 'inserts appendix 2

GoTo Saveletter



Exit Sub



Saveletter:
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
        "File Path for first document to be attached to main document"
    
    
    

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
        "File Path for first document to be attached to main document" & Item1 & "_Agreed Document.docx" _
        , FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
        
        
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True



End Sub
```

Comment: See also Boiler from Word MVP Graham Mayor: http://www.gmayor.com/Boiler.htm It may do what you want without you writing the code.

Comment: For a comprehensive solution, though not for specified ranges, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43339-combine-multiple-word-documents.html

Answer (score 0):

Your title could easily give the impression that you are going through the [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range) of content in an MS Word document file, rather than going through a list of file ranges.

I haven't seen all of your code and user interface to get a precise idea of how your code actually works, especially the list box, ex. the line "Number = ListBox1.Value". However, If you want to

> I need the word macro to go into each of these documents.

Why not add the line

> Selection.InsertFile ……

into the loop **while ......Wend** ? like this:

```vb
While File_Name <> ""
    File = File_Name
    File_Name = Dir
    Selection.InsertFile FileName:="File Path for second document to be attached to main document" & File _
        , Range:="", ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False 'inserts appendix 2

Wend
```

You can refer to this web page: [Selection.InsertFile method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertfile), there is a simple code example you need, I copy it below to conveniently read (so even after the web page is modified it is still here to check out.)

> This example creates a new document and then inserts the contents of each text file in the C:\TMP folder into the new document.

```vb
Documents.Add 
ChDir "C:\TMP" 
myName = Dir("*.TXT") 
While myName <> "" 
 With Selection 
 .InsertFile FileName:=myName, ConfirmConversions:=False 
 .InsertParagraphAfter 
 .InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage 
 .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd 
 End With 
 myName = Dir() 
Wend
```